# Change disc color of arrow in listview

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile, jquery-mobile-listview

Where is the responsible CSS definition where I could change the disc color of a linked list item? I can't find it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/vMCKD/

```
.ui-listview .ui-btn .ui-btn-inner .ui-icon-arrow-r {
    background-color: red !important;
}
```

You can replace **.ui-listview** with an id of your listview, so that this change can only affect certain listview/s.

Answer (score 0):

Using ThemeRoller and searching my desired color I found it:

```
.ui-icon,
.ui-icon-searchfield:after {
    background-color: #a5141b /*{global-icon-color}*/;
    background-color: rgba(165,20,27,1) /*{global-icon-disc}*/;
    background-image: url(images/icons-18-white.png) /*{global-icon-set}*/;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    -webkit-border-radius:              9px;
    border-radius:                      9px;
}
```